# Adding bytes to PE without affecting execution

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

As the title says, how would this be done? If I added one byte at the start of the opcode, it would push the adresses in memory with one byte. if you dont understand the question:

original:

```
0x1  mov ecx, 10
0x2  mov eax, 1
0x3  inc eac
0x4  cmp eax
0x5  jl 0x3
```

Added byte:

```
0x1  NOP
0x2  mov ecx, 10
0x3  mov eax, 1
0x4  inc eac
0x5  cmp eax
0x6  jl 0x3
```

Would I have to manually set every jmp, call etc. or are there any other ways to do it?

Comment: You'd have to manually inspect every memory address used in in a program to see if it needs to be adjusted. In a non-trivial program this isn't practical as the addresses you need to fix could be anywhere. Also note that most of the instructions you listed are more than 1 byte long.

Comment: Hmm, this might not be an exact duplicate.  The dup-target I picked is about one specific method of adding new code (put it in a new section and replace some existing insns with a jmp to it), but Jean-François's answer points out other techniques.

Answer (score 2):

bad idea as it would

- shift some relative jumps (not all of them)
- shift relocation offset if code is not position-independent

When I used to crack games, I put NOPs INSTEAD of code and that was all right, but sometimes you needed to do more than that so:

Alternatives:

- find a free/unused program zone (like unreachable robustness code for instance) and move some original code there. Then jsr to it and add your custom code.
- disassemble the executable so it can be reassembled and add your code as will. This method requires you to identify all code & data sections so it's more difficult but in the end you can add anything to the program.

Comment: If I disassemble the executable. How would I know whether a byte is an instruction or part of a memory position? For example: I might be looking for mov instruction 0x89 and find it in all 0x89 movs, but also in mov eax, dword_0x4C89.

Comment: @JF: let me know if you think I should re-open this.  I may have been hasty in dup-hammering it.

Comment: @PeterCordes that's kind of you but I think you are right. The linked answer is excellent and very complete.